# Which errors should I catch for my Entity Framework queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application (running on .NET 6), where I have a database of some customers.

The purpose of the application is simply to let a user input a bunch of constraints that will filter the customers in the database, and return the filtered list of customers, and then display them to the user.

I have a controller action, which accepts the constraints query, and it looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Query(QueryModel query)
{
    var customers = await _context.Customers.AsQueryable().FilterCustomerList(query);

    ViewBag.Name = query.Name;
    ViewBag.Age = query.Age;
    ViewBag.SalesPersonName = query.salespersonName;

    return View("Index", customers);
}
```

and then this function is filtering the customers:

```
public static async Task<List<CustomerModel>> FilterCustomerList(this IQueryable<CustomerModel> customersQuery, QueryModel query)
{
    customersQuery = customersQuery
    .Include(x => x.Adress)
    .Include(x => x.purchases).ThenInclude(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.purchases).ThenInclude(x => x.SalesPerson.Adress)
    .Where(query.Name != default, x => x.Name.Equals(query.Name))
    .Where(query.Surname != default, x => x.Surname.Equals(query.Surname))
    .Where(query.Age != default, x => x.Age.Equals(query.Age))
    .Where(query.Country != default, x => x.Adress.Country.Equals(query.Country))
    .Where(query.Town != default, x => x.Adress.Town.Equals(query.Town))
    .Where(query.ZipCode != default, x => x.Adress.ZipCode.Equals(query.ZipCode))
    .Where(query.Street != default, x => x.Adress.street.Equals(query.Street))
    .Where(query.HouseNr != default, x => x.Adress.HouseNumber.Equals(query.HouseNr))
    .Where(query.To != query.From, x => x.Created > query.From && x.Created < query.To)
    .Where(query.purchaseDateFrom != query.purchaseDateTo, x => x.purchases.Any(
        x => x.OrderDate > query.purchaseDateFrom && x.OrderDate < query.purchaseDateTo))
    .Where(query.model != default, x => x.purchases.Any(p => p.Car.Model.Equals(query.model)))
    .Where(query.make != default, x => x.purchases.Any(p => p.Car.Make.Equals(query.make)))
    .Where(query.color != default, x => x.purchases.Any(p => p.Car.CarColor == query.color))
    .Where(query.paidPrice != default, x => x.purchases.Any(p => p.PricePaid.Equals(query.recPrice)))
    .Where(query.recPrice != default,
        x => x.purchases.Any(p => p.Car.RecommendedPrice.Equals(query.recPrice)))
    .Where(query.recPriceLow != default && query.recPriceTop != default, x
        => x.purchases.Any(p =>
            p.Car.RecommendedPrice > query.recPriceLow && p.Car.RecommendedPrice < query.recPriceTop))
    .Where(query.paidPriceTop != default && query.paidPriceLow != default, x
        => x.purchases.Any(p => p.PricePaid > query.paidPriceLow && p.PricePaid < query.paidPriceTop))
    .Where(query.salespersonName != default,
        c => c.purchases.Any(p => p.SalesPerson.Name.Equals(query.salespersonName)))
    .Where(query.salespersonJobTitle != default,
        c => c.purchases.Any(x => x.SalesPerson.JobTitle == query.salespersonJobTitle))
    .Where(query.salesPersonSalary != default, c => c.purchases.Any(x => query.salesPersonSalary.Equals(x
        .SalesPerson.Salary)))
    .Where(query.salesPersonSalaryFrom != default && query.salesPersonSalaryFrom != default, c =>
        c.purchases.Any(x => x.SalesPerson.Salary < query.salesPersonSalaryFrom &&
                             x.SalesPerson.Salary > query.salesPersonSalaryTo))
    .Where(query.SalesPersonCountry != default,
        c => c.purchases.Any(x => x.SalesPerson.Adress.Country.Equals(query.SalesPersonCountry)))
    .Where(query.SalesPersonTown != default,
        c => c.purchases.Any(x => x.SalesPerson.Adress.Town.Equals(query.SalesPersonTown)))
    .Where(query.SalesPersonZipCode != default, c => c.purchases.Any(x =>
        x.SalesPerson.Adress.ZipCode.Equals(query.ZipCode)))
    .Where(query.SalesPersonStreet != default, c => c.purchases.Any(x =>
        x.SalesPerson.Adress.street.Equals(query.SalesPersonStreet)))
    .Where(query.salesPersonHouseNr != default, c => c.purchases.Any(x =>
        x.SalesPerson.Adress.HouseNumber.Equals(query.salesPersonHouseNr)));

switch (query.sortBy)
{
    case SortBy.Age_desc:
    {
        customersQuery = customersQuery.OrderByDescending(c => c.Age);
        break;
    }
    case SortBy.CreationDate_desc:
    {
        customersQuery = customersQuery.OrderByDescending(c => c.Created);
        break;
    }
    case SortBy.Age_asc:
    {
        customersQuery = customersQuery.OrderBy(c => c.Age);
        break;
    }
    case SortBy.CreationDate_asc:
    {
        customersQuery = customersQuery.OrderBy(c => c.Created);
        break;
    }
}

var customers = await customersQuery
    .ToListAsync();

return customers;
}
```

Which is just a very long block of where clauses.

Now, I'm thinking I should have something in place which could catch any errors emitted during these lookups.

I can't really figure out which exception I might expect when I am only doing lookups though, and can't figure out how to provoke any either, so I could find out.

Also, I would like to be able to communicate to my controller that an error has happened, and that an sensible error should be displayed.

Would the best/most normal practice, just be to throw the error and have some standard error page show, or could I let the controller action handle the error?

Comment: Queries will not throw exceptions.  It's possible you will get exception if part of `query` is null and you dereference it, but that's not a SQL problem.

Answer (score -1):

> Now, I'm thinking I should have something in place which could catch
> any errors emitted during these lookups.

If you are not certain which exceptions you get in what situations, use your debugger and some test code to find out which exceptions you actually may expect:

```
// TODO: create one of your error conditions
try
{
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType()); // what is the real exception?
}
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54741826/entity-framework-how-to-catch-any-error) to know more